# cscart - display product timestamp on category and prouct detail page

Tags: cs-cart

I'm trying to display timestamp of product in cscart on category and product detail page but couldn't get. It capture date while creating the product. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ishlO.jpg)

Any clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get **timestamp** from the table `cscart_products.`

Answer (score 0):

```
{$product.timestamp|date_format:"`$settings.Appearance.date_format`"}
```

The value should be added in .tpl or use a hooks to add it, the variable (**$product**) depend on .tpl you want to display (category page, product page, blocks ...)